# Set width of the scrollable element to the full value (visible + invisible parts)

Tags: html, css

I got the container, which width is the half of a page. That container includes several item collections (rows). Each row includes big amount of items. You can see only limited count of items, other ones can be discovered by horizontal scroll.

Please, see the snippet below.

```css
.container {
  width: 50%;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.items {
  height: 100px;
  background: #ccc;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.item {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30%;
  height: 50px;
  background: #efc;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.shadow {
  outline: none;
  border: 2px solid #3a53ed;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #9ecaed;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="items">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="items shadow">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have `shadow` class, which adds bright borders and shadow to an element. I want to be able to apply that class to any item collection (row). I mean, not only for visible part, but for the whole.

The problem is that width of a row element is equal to visible part. How can I make that width to be equal to the full long width (based on all items' width)?

**UPDATE**: layout (mostly) and scrolling behaviour should remain the same

Thank you.

Comment: I suppose you want the grey background to be full length as well ?

Comment: @Ced in that snippet it can be done by adding background color to the `div.container` element; but all those things are just symptoms. solution of width problem will fix all other problems - border, background color, etc...

Comment: Did my answer help you  ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you not something like it.

```css
.container {
  width: 50%;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.items {
  height: 100px;
  background: #ccc;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.item {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30%;
  height: 50px;
  background: #efc;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.shadow {
  outline: none;
  border: 2px solid #3a53ed;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #9ecaed;
}
```

```html
   

 <div class="container">
   <div class="items">
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="items shadow">
   <div class="container">
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I have to stick to existing HTML layout. So, it requires just CSS changes.

Comment: np, will do :) in the meantime, your solution breaks scrolling behaviour, which is unwanted

Comment: do you have any other thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

The actual default behavior is buggy tbh, I would have assumed it would have worked as you intended it to from the get go.

Anyway, I don't think it's doable without javascript but I could be wrong. 
 The reason is that your `item` are of `width: 30%`, so if you changed the `width` of `items` to get the appropriate border, then the width of `item` would change as well.. See where I'm getting at ?

- Having the shadow class on `items` is a no go, since even if we changed its width, it would change the width of contained `item`s, so we have to put it somewhere else.

-

```
.shadow{
   box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  outline: none;
  border: 2px solid #3a53ed;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #9ecaed;
}
```

So with that out of the way, how would we give the correct width to shadow ? I don't think we can without js.

With some javascript you can grab the width of the container and apply it to a "shadow" div.

```js
let ctnr = document.querySelector(".container");
let width = ctnr.scrollWidth;
let sel = document.querySelectorAll(".shadow");

sel.forEach( s => {
    s.style.width = width + "px";
});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 50%;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  background: #ccc;
}

.items {
  height: 100px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.item {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30%;
  height: 50px;
  background: #efc;
  border: 1px solid;
}
.outer{
  }
.sel{
  position: relative;
}
.shadow{
   box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  outline: none;
  border: 2px solid #3a53ed;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #9ecaed;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="items">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="items sel">
    <div class="shadow"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```